# Netbeans Cannot connect to server. Cause: The cipher 'aes252-cbc' is required

Tags: java, netbeans

I am getting the following error when trying to create a Remote Connection within Netbeans for a PHP Project:

Netbeans Cannot connect to server XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX.
Cause: The cipher 'aes252-cbc' is required, but is not available.

I have googled this and searched Stackoverflow however the only solution found was to install Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files which I have done from this link:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html

I have restarted my Windows 7 Machine after installing those and I am still getting the error.

Comment: Where did you extract the file `jce_policy-8.zip`?

Comment: C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\lib\security

Comment: Are you running Java code or PHP code? For PHP code you might need some other solution. For Java code please show your code (snippet) to reproduce the error.

Comment: I am using Netbeans on my Windows 7 machine so there is no "code." Netbeans relies on Java to run.

Comment: If Netbeans is running using th JVM from `C:\Program Files\Java\jre8` and the missed cipher is `aes256-cbc` (not aes252-cbc) then you should describe what steps you do to connect to the server.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up switching to Eclipse and it just works seamlessly.